# Conditional resource get destroyed if count parameter is set to 0

Tags: azure, terraform

I have a VNET/App Service integration requirement. This requires the creation of a VPN gateway.

Once the integration is completed a certificate (generated by the App Service) is associated to the point-to-site configuration of the VPN Gateway.

If i need to run terraform once again because i need to perform some changes it detects that the VPN gateway must be destroyed because in Azure it has a certificate!

I thought about using the count parameter on the VPN gateway resource, but if i set count = 0 according to a variable i get the same problem.

Any piece of advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `ignore_changes` statement in the lifecycle of your resource. This is an example of what I use for some instances:

```
lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
        "user_data",
        "instance_type",
        "root_block_device.0.volume_size",
        "ebs_optimized",
        "tags",
    ]
}
```

It is set in the resource definition as follows (just to get an idea how to place it in the definition):

```
resource "aws_instance" "worker_base" {
  count         = "..."
  instance_type = "..."
  user_data     = "..."

  lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [
        "user_data",
        "instance_type",
        "root_block_device.0.volume_size",
        "ebs_optimized",
        "tags",
      ]
  }

  tags = {
      Name = "..."
  }

  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = "..."
    volume_size           = "..."
    volume_type           = "..."
  }
}
```

Now, from the `terraform plan` output you should see the parameter that changed so that a new resource is required. Try setting this in the `ignore_changes` list...

Comment: I encountered an error: "50:         "root_block_device.0.volume_size",

Dot must be followed by attribute name."

Comment: @CalvinZhou can you show the full resource definitions please?